# Too many pool exhaustion errors with jdbc-pool

Tags: java, jdbc

I have an app that began using `jdbc-pool` for MySQL connection handling in the past month. Prior to that I'd been using Apache's `commons-dbcp`. I switched to jdbc-pool after reading some analysis that showed it's faster, is being better maintained, etc. However, I've started noticing that *a lot* more of my users are seeing pool exhaustion errors.

I don't know if it's related to switching from commons to jdbc-pool, but it seemed to start at that time and I'm considering making a build of our product that reverts and giving that to people with db errors to see what impact it has.

I've written up a document that helps them troubleshoot by adjusting the pool connections, increasing max wait, etc. However, I'm starting to see a lot of people report pool exhaustion errors even when their applications are essentially idle. A `show full processlist` seems to show 19 connections in "sleep" in 1 connection active.

I run the application a lot in both production and dev environments and have never had an issue. I'm better at managing my mysql envirornments but competitor products with weaker pooling systems have no such issues.

I've spent a lot of time reading the jdbc and pooling docs, but **am I doing something that would cause poor performance**?

These are examples of our db connection code with the defaults we use in place.

```
// Called once on application start, connects to the database
public DataSource initDbPool(){
    String dns = "jdbc:mysql://"+config.getString("prism.mysql.hostname")+":"+config.getString("prism.mysql.port")+"/"+config.getString("prism.mysql.database");
    pool = new DataSource();
    pool.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    pool.setUrl(dns);
    pool.setUsername( /*username*/ );
    pool.setPassword( /*password*/ );
    pool.setInitialSize( 10 );
    pool.setMaxActive( 20 );
    pool.setMaxIdle( 10 );
    pool.setMaxWait( 30000 );
    pool.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    pool.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    return pool;
}

// Called from various classes that need to run queries
public static Connection dbc(){
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = pool.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print("Database connection failed. " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
```

[The actual code can be seen here.](https://github.com/prism/Prism/blob/master/src/main/java/me/botsko/prism/Prism.java#L279)

I never do much fancy with queries either. We're constantly running batch insert queries but we've optimized that with a queue system and batch inserts so it's extremely fast and uses as little overhead as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you have `close()` but not in a `finally` block. It means if exception occurs, the connection will be lost. I suspect that `commons-dhcp` doesn't handle leaked connections the same way as `jdbc-pool`.

There is `removeAbandoned` configuration option, which is `off` by default, because it is the Right Thing™. But as I understand, it doesn't give any guarantees, because it closes them by timeout. If you would have a lot of exceptions in a short period of time, it could exhaust the pool. So, better approach is to close all connections in a `finally` block always.

Comment: So you mean something like this: http://pste.me/TmcFT ? The close itself requires a try/catch, but I assume I can ignore that? Or are you suggesting I use the finally everywhere I close connections? Or are you suggesting that I close the pool connections entirely, and then try to reconnect?

Comment: And to clarify, it's very possible to have a lot of exceptions in a short period. Our application is constantly recording data and if something triggers the pool exhaustion errors, they always seem to start piling up and applications hang/crash.

Comment: I've gone through my code and fully see the issue now. If exceptions are raised it may not be closing connections and that can lead to leaks, so I've moved everything into a finally block and am having some users try it.

Comment: @BotskoNet yes, usually you should do `...finally{try{con.close()}catch(Exception e){log.error(e);}}`. Or use java 7 `try-with-resources` block. Closing a connection from a pool means returning a physical connection into the pool.